# Disable root account in Ubuntu?

Tags: root, password

I was asked for root credentials to setup my printer in Ubuntu. This seemed to be caused by a bug. And the suggested workaround is to create a root password. Since it is default that no root password is used in Ubuntu, i wonder how i could revert this changes.

Once i have set a password for root, is there a method to disable it again?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

According to Ubuntu online help

> Ubuntu developers made a conscientious
>   decision to disable the administrative
>   root account by default in all Ubuntu
>   installations. This does not mean that
>   the root account has been deleted or
>   that it may not be accessed. It merely
>   has been given a password which
>   matches no possible encrypted value,
>   therefore may not log in directly by
>   itself.

If you want to enable root account simply give it some password using

```
sudo passwd
```

When you enter this command you will be asked for new password. The password you enter will be the password for root account so be careful and choose a strong password.

To disable the root login use

```
sudo passwd -l root
```

This will disable the login using root user name i.e your system will be back to previous state.

If you want more information on Ubuntu user management read the [official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/user-management.html).

Comment: Use `sudo passwd -S root` to check if locked or not (will have L in output instead of P).

Comment: Which version did they make this change on?

Answer (score 36):

```
sudo usermod -p '!' root
```

That will set the root account to have an unusable password.

You can also lock the account to stop people logging in.

```
sudo passwd -l root
```

Either approach should do what you want. You don't need to do both.

Comment: I don't get it. Why an unusable password?

Comment: Unusable in that you cannot log in with it. It's what the password starts off as AFAIK.

Comment: when i disable it with: sudo passwd -l root. do i have to remember the current root password for future use, perhaps if i someday want to activate root password again?

Comment: @NES no you dont have to remember it. you reset the password and time with "sudo passwd"

Comment: The first command will return the `/etc/shadow` file to its out-of-the-box state, which seems like maybe the better approach of the two.

Comment: Disclaimer: From `man passwd`: Note that this does not disable the account. The user may still be able to login using another authentication token (e.g. an SSH key).