# What to do after entering sudo password as plain text into terminal?

Tags: sudo, password, bash-history

A few days ago i entered my sudo password (and hence my root password) into the terminal as plain text by mistake.

I wanted to change my password, but forgot to enter the `passwd` command, and only noticed so after already typing out my whole password.

After having noticed this, i immediately changed my password - for real this time.

Now, are there any additional steps i have to take after this in order to keep my user account, as well as (more importantly) my system as secure as possible?

One thing that was suggested to me was going into the bash_history via `nano` and deleting the (maybe existing) plain text entry of my password.

Is that a viable strategy, and if so, are there any other steps i might have to take?

Comment: Close any terminal windows (and other possible bash processes). Then start your file manager, make it show hidden files, select `.bash_history` in your home directory and edit the file (search for and remove all lines containing your old password). Finally save the file and check that the editor has not created a backup file `.bash_history~`. - But the most important action was to change your password to something very different from the previous password.

Comment: Is this a "better" solution than using ```nano``` from within the terminal to open and edit ```.bash_history```? Or what are the differences between the two, especially since you explicitly stated to close all terminal windows and bash processes for your solution?

Comment: When a terminal window is open, it will again write from memory to the file `.bash_history` (when you close it), but if no terminal window is open, and no `bash` process is running, you can edit the file and save the edits without interference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's a personal computer you are mostly fine. Even if someone was snooping on you how would it now that what you typed was your password?

Anyway, changing it is a good idea and if you have changed it and it's not close to what it was before, for example going from `mypass` to `mypass1` you are almost good to go.

If you're paranoid about it check for any other account that "might have been added" to your system. This might help you to get a list of users:

```
awk -F':' '$3>1000 && $3<2000 {print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

or just go through:

```
compgen -u
```

for anything suspicious. And make sure root user has been locked: [Disable root account in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20450/disable-root-account-in-ubuntu)

You already know about `~/.bash_history` so I'm not going through it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. For purposes of keeping a vague example, it was like going from ```mypass1``` to ```yourword2```. And since i never added a root password to my system, i understand it should be locked as default, right?

Comment: Yeah, suggestion is just there in case.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. And regarding the password and the example given - I guess it's also a safer bet to completely change the "convention" of password creation. However i am unsure if this would be overcompensating in this situation.

Comment: In general I recommend using more secure and complex passwords. Things like `aivhl amvi ..`. In this situation... your just fine. no worry ;)

Comment: Thank you for the help. Will try the suggested solutions tomorrow or on the weekend. If some things are really unclear for me, i might report back. But so far i now have a nice idea of what to do next. So, thanks. Have a nice day :)

Comment: Anytime. You are welcome... :)